# WebDev.Webserver40.exe error (not a valid win32 application) - can't compile in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-construction, webdev.webserver, windows-xp-sp3

Everytime I try to compile in Visual Studio 2010 I get the error

> Unable to launch the ASP.NET Development server. Unable to start program 'C\path.......\Webdev.Webserver40.exe

I also tried to execute this file (`Webdev.Webserver40.exe`) and I get this error:

> WebDev.WebServer40.exe is not a valid win32 application

I already turned off every firewall I have, and I already tried changing the .NET framework of any project, changed to different speceific ports and it's still failing...

What could be happening?

I have Windows XP SP3

Comment: Maybe you got a 64bit webserver installed ?

Comment: according to the webserver.exe.manifest is 32bit :/.. my pc architecture is also 32bit

Comment: Maybe the file is corrupt somehow, could you copy one over from another machine to test ?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same error. Seems like somehow the webserver embebbed in VS2010 got corrupted.

If you try to Debug a WebSite, the error is "Unable to launch ASP.NET Development Server".

If you try to Debug a Web Application, the error message points to the path of the server.

It's installed under this folder:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0

The two executables WebDev.WebServer20.EXE and WebDev.WebServer40.EXE were really corrupted (getting error "not a valid win32 application" when try to run).

I had to go to instalation DVD and selected "Change or Remove Microsoft Visual Studio 2010" in the Main Menu.

After that:

- Add or Remove features
- Uninstall Web Developer

When the uninstalling is complete, do it again:

- Add or Remove features
- Install Web Developer

Now everything works just fine.

I hope the same resolve to you.